# When does an autonomous transaction end for Oracle?

Tags: oracle, transactions, ddl

As I understand autonomous transactions (in the Oracle world), the autonomous transaction ends when a commit or rollback is issued. However, I have just written a procedure as an autonomous transaction because I needed to isolate a piece of DDL that changes a tablespace from read only to read write.

Then I started thinking about when the autonomous bit ended.

The problem is that there is an implicit commit both before and after the DDL is executed. Now, I happen to know that my code has the desired effect, so I can only surmise that the initial 'empty' commit is not the end of the autonomous transaction and the subsequent commit is. What is surprising is that I cannot find any mention of this on the internet.

Can anyone point me towards documentation that would explain my conundrum?

Comment: Oracle docs: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16508/transact.htm#i7733

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A routine declared autonomous is autonomous for the whole routine and doesn't end when a commit or rollback is issued.
See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#i36056) in oracle docs:

Comment: "When you enter the executable section of an autonomous routine, the main transaction suspends. When you exit the routine, the main transaction resumes." That explains all, thank you very much for clearing up my misunderstanding.